# how to get image id of current flipper View and to set that image to user background?

Tags: android, viewflipper

This code is working fine but when i try to set current image to user phone background i geting error. Can't figure out how to set a resources from the current image on the screen. how to set this line here

```
myWallpaperManager.setResource(vf.indexOfChild(vf.getCurrentView()));
```

to use current image id of view?

this is the error:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x2
here is my code.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, OnClickListener {

protected GestureDetector gestureScanner;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private Button next,previous,set;
private ViewFlipper vf;
private Animation animFlipInNext,animFlipOutNext, animFlipInPrevious, animFlipOutPrevious;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

    //vf for viewflipper
    vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
    animFlipInNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipinnext);
    animFlipOutNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipoutnext);
    animFlipInPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipinprevious);
    animFlipOutPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipoutprevious);

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    set.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == next) {
        vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInNext);
        vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutNext);
        vf.showNext();
    }
    if (v == previous) {
        vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInPrevious);
        vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutPrevious);
        vf.showPrevious();
    }
    if(v == set) {
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
       try {
           myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.arnab); // how to set this line to use the resources of current image on screen?

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper is successfully changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//this is the part to handle Gesture Listener
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
}
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e){
    return true;
}
//FLING gesture listener
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1,MotionEvent e2,float velocityX,float velocityY){
    try {
        if(e1.getX() > e2.getX() && Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInPrevious);
            vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutPrevious);
            vf.showPrevious();
        }else if (e1.getX() < e2.getX() && e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInNext);
            vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutNext);
            vf.showNext();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1,MotionEvent e2,float distanceX,float distanceY){
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code :

```
vf.indexOfChild(vf.getCurrentView());
```

Tells you which page of the ViewFlipper you are on. If the flipper contains only images (not nested within another layout) then what you probably need to do is along the lines of:

```
myWallpaperManager.setDrawable( ((ImageView) vf.getCurrentView()).getDrawable() );
```

**To explain** what Lines 50 & 51 in the code you just [linked here](http://prntscr.com/2i4jgr) does:

```
[Line 50] vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper01)
[Line 51] vf.setDisplayedChild(vf.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper01)));
```

What line 51 says is "Set my child view to the index of my child view that is actually myself". If that line doesn't make sense in English, it makes even less sense in Java where a view *cannot* contain itself as a child view

Comment: i tryed that line it tells me 
  The method 

      getDrawable()

 is undefined for the type View
how to define getDrawable?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's not a very safe way to handle this though. You may wish to store a map of index to resource id.

Comment: I hadn't tried wallpaper manager, I was just illustrating your incorrect use of indexOfChild. I either suggest using a  Map as above or use setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) and convert your drawable

Comment: i tried like this [link](http://prntscr.com/2i4jgr) 
here is the logcat [link](http://prntscr.com/2i4ki0)
and its does not work.

Answer (score 0):

bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) vf.getCurrentView()).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

This my code!

`